# how to send registration email after user must have registered using the laravel built in MustEmailVerify

Tags: php, laravel

here is my smtp configuration in my .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=coin****.******
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=support@coin***.******
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@coin***.******
MAIL_FROM_NAME=COIN****
```

here is my App/user.php file which implements implements MustVerifyEmail

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','email','password','role', 'status'
     ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }

    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }

    public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Account');
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(transactions::class);
    }

    public function withdrawals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(withdrawals::class);
    }

    public function funds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(funds::class);
    }
}
```

Here is my app/routes/web.php file where i have also added the Email Verification Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
Route::get('/pricing', function () {
    return view('pricing');
});
Route::get('/services', function () {
    return view('services');
});
Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

// Show Register Page & Login Page
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@show')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@show')->name('register')->middleware('guest');


// Register & Login User
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate');
Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@register');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'DashboardController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@redirect')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
    Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
    Route::get('/transfer', 'FundController@create')->name('transfer');
    Route::post('/create/make_transfer/{$id}',['as'=>'transfer.store','uses'=>'FundController@store']);
    Route::get('/withdraw', 'WithdrawController@create')->name('withdraw');
    Route::post('/create/withdraw_fund/{$id}',['as'=>'withdraw.store','uses'=>'WithdrawController@store']);

});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('users.index');
    Route::get('users/edit/{id}',['as'=>'users.edit','uses'=>'UserController@edit']);
    Route::patch('users/{id}',['as'=>'users.update','uses'=>'UserController@update']);
    Route::post('users/destory', 'UserController@destory')->name('users.destory');

    Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountController@index')->name('accounts.index');
    Route::get('accounts/edit/{user_id}',['as'=>'accounts.edit','uses'=>'AccountController@edit']);
    Route::patch('accounts/{user_id}',['as'=>'accounts.update','uses'=>'AccountController@update']);
    Route::post('accounts/destory', 'AccountController@destory')->name('accounts.destory');

    Route::get('/transactions', 'TransactionController@index')->name('transactions.index');
    Route::get('transactions/edit/{id}',['as'=>'transactions.edit','uses'=>'TransactionController@edit']);
    Route::patch('trnsactions/{id}',['as'=>'transactions.update','uses'=>'TransactionController@update']);
    Route::post('transactions/destory', 'TransactionController@destory')->name('transactions.destory');

});
```

also here app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php file i have added the Email Verification Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

But for reasons unknown to me i don't get the default laravel verification page which shows that the mail has been sent rather i get redirected straight to the login page and the verification mail is never sent.
i have successfully used this method in other smaller laravel site i have worked on and it perfectly works okay, i am new to laravel and would really like for this to work out for me , so please i need all the help i an get, thanks

Comment: please could you be more specific where i should call $user and where i should add the controller am new to laravel could you be a little more detailed

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your route file... you are registering successfully the users?

Comment: thanks it worked the message/mail now gets sent, i appreciate the help but is there anyway i could get the laravel custom verify your email page to show after the user registers instead of redirecting the user to the login page straight up

Comment: Yes the users are successfully registered, and thanks to you the registration email is now been sent but the verify your email page dosen't come up as it did in my previous project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make accessible some route only to those users that has verified email, you need to use the `verified` middleware, not the `auth` middleware, so something like:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i keep getting this error message"Swift_Transport Exception
Cannot send message without a sender address" ...could anyone help, my code above is as the same in my new project and this method worked well in my old project above... i cant seem to spot the problem in my new project

Comment: @DarrlySmith has nothing to do with middleware, you have other problems with the Mail, but has nothing to do with this

Comment: how do i spot the problems with the mail ....everything was working fine until i tried implementing it in this new project

Comment: @DarrlySmith open a new question on SO, or look for similar questions